# Mapping xml-attribute using resteasy

Tags: rest, tomcat6, resteasy

I'm using resteasy and have some problem.

There is some service on remote server. For example, when I go to url

"http://some.site.com/Login/my_login/my_passowrd" service returns me xml:

```
< LoginToken>
  < success>true< /success>
  < token>23324473-897b-408b-b096-bf2cddad33< /token>
< /LoginToken>
```

I've wrote class for mapping:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "LoginToken")
public class LoginToken {

  @XmlElement(name="success")
  private String success;

  @XmlElement(name="token")
  private String token;

  public String getSuccess() {
      return success;
    }

  public String getToken() {
      return token;
    }
}
```

..and another code for testing:

```
final String loginUrl "http://some.site.com/Login/{login}/{password}";
ResteasyProviderFactory instance = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
RegisterBuiltin.register(instance);

ClientRequestFactory client = new ClientRequestFactory();

LoginToken ct = client.get(loginUrl, LoginToken.class, "user", "123456");

System.out.println(ct.getSuccess() + " " + ct.getToken());
```

after running this example I receive result:

> true 23324473-897b-408b-b096-bf2cddad33

But server can returns another xml:

```
< LoginToken xmlns="some.site.com/login/api/domain" mlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  < success>true< /success>
  < token>23324473-897b-408b-b096-bf2cddad33< /token>
< /LoginToken>
```

and i have unmarshall error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshalException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"some.site.com/login/api/domain", local:"LoginToken"). Expected elements are <{}LoginToken>
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.readFrom(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:86)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:46)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108)
...
```

Question: how can I map xml-namespace using resteasy? Please, help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'he resove the problem.
It's needed to use namespace for each element and all tags are case sensitive!